# Receive one by one multiple ajax request in same sequence as the each-loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, each

I want to do a each-iteration in jQuery and for each value I want to make a Ajax-request. 
Each result from ajax should be displayed one by one. So not all at once (at the end of alle ajax-queries).
For each value of the content-array the ajax-request should output some data (into html) in same sequence. After showing some html-data, the next ajax request should be fired. etc, etc.

**Comment**
It is not about the literal data in this example (i know this data/httpstatus can be received in many other and easier ways). It's all about getting the correct html-output one-by-one dynamically in sequence/same order as the content-array.

**The problem**
In de example below (and in the live-preview at http://www.heyhugo.nl/test/ ) the results of each ajax request will show up in the html, but the sequence has mixed and does not follow the order of the content-array (url's).

**Unwanted solution**
"async: false" in the ajax-request is NOT the solution for me. This will show all results at once.

I've tried many suggestion from stackoverflow and the jquery-docs, but i can not find a solution at all after doing research many days.

Who can help me and/or can re-write this example?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var content = ['http://www.amazon.com','http://www.nu.nl','http://www.google.nl', 'http://www.google.de', 'http://www.google.com', 'http://www.google.fr'];

            $('#body').ready(function(){    // load function if body has loaded.
                $.fn.analyzeURLS(content);
            });

            $.fn.analyzeURLS = function(content) {
                $.each( content, function( key, value ) {
                    var URL = value;    // returns httpstatus for each url
                    $.when(
                        $.ajax({
                            type : "GET",
                            //async: false,
                            url : "checkurl.php",
                            dataType : "json",
                            data: { url : URL }
                        })
                        // the ajax request will return a json-string: {"httpstatus":"200"}
                    )
                    .then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    {
                        httpstatus = data.httpstatus;   // SET httpstatus return from ajax request
                        var addDiv = '<div class="httpstatus">' + URL + ' - ' + httpstatus + '</div>'; // create div to append in html
                        $( "#results" ).append( addDiv );   // append div in html
                    })
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: 2014-08-05

I found a solution for the question above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        var content = ['http://www.amazon.com','http://www.nu.nl','http://www.google.nl', 'http://www.google.de', 'http://www.google.com', 'http://www.google.fr'];
        var content_length = content.length;

        // load function if body has loaded.
        $('#body').ready(function(){
            $.fn.analyzeURLajax(0);
        });

        $.fn.analyzeURLajax = function(key) {
            $.when(
                $.ajax({
                    type : "GET",
                    url : "checkurl.php",
                    dataType : "json",
                    data: { url : content[key] }
                })
            )
            .then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
            {
                var addDiv = '<div class="httpstatus">' + content[key] + ' - http-status:' + data.httpstatus + '</div>';
                $( "#results" ).append( addDiv );

                next_key = (key + 1);
                if(next_key < content_length) {
                    $.fn.analyzeURLajax(next_key);
                }
            })
        };
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

the issue is, there's no guarantee that the AJAX requests will finish in any order, it is asynchronous after all. You have 2 options as far as I can see it: instead of `$.each()`, fire off the AJAX calls in sequence (make `content` a global, remember the key and send it to the next) or, have the AJAX calls wait, so they only modify the page once the previous one in sequence was inserted. (This would involve significantly modifying the code so I opted to show Option 1 instead).

Option 1:

```
function parseQueryString(query) {
    var queries = query.split('&');
    var i,len,temp,params;
    params = [];
    for (i=0,len = queries.length;i<len;i++) {
        temp = queries[i].split('=');
        params[temp[0]]=temp[1];
    }
    return params;
}

$.fn.analyzeUrlsContent = array();
$.fn.analyzeURLS = function(content) {
            $.fn.analyzeUrlsContent = content;
            $.fn.analyzeURLajax(0); 
    };

$.fn.analyzeURLajax = function(key) {
     $.when(
             $.ajax({
                        type : "GET",
                        //async: false,
                        url : "checkurl.php",
                        dataType : "json",
                        data: { url : $.fn.analyzeUrlsContent[key],'key' : key}
                    })
                    // the ajax request will return a json-string: {"httpstatus":"200"}
             ).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    httpstatus = data.httpstatus;   // SET httpstatus return from ajax request
                    var addDiv = '<div class="httpstatus">' + URL + ' - ' + httpstatus + '</div>'; // create div to append in html
                    $( "#results" ).append( addDiv );   // append div in html
                     var query = parseQueryString(this.data)
                     if(query.key < ($.fn.analyzeUrlsContent.length -1)) {
                         $.fn.analyzeURLajax(query.key+1);
                     }
            })
    };
```

Comment: Your solution did not work properly for me. But your suggestion put me in the right direction and i found the solution.

Comment: Could you share you solution @GuidoLemmens2